# How can I get my iPad 2 to view a website on a laptop over an adhoc network?

Tags: ipad, ad-hoc

I have setup a laptop with iis and have a test website running on it.  I have created an adhoc network between my laptop (running Windows 7) and my Ipad 2. On the laptop I can enter a url in firefox and it knows it is a local site, by entering details of this into the hosts file.

When I try to enter the url into the browser on the Ipad 2, I get a message of: Safari cannot open the page because it is not connected to the internet.

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can the iPad connect to the laptop at all? Do you rely on using a URL versus IP for host configuration/virtual hosting?

Comment: You can't hit the web site by IP because IIS is not configured to route a request for a given IP to a given web site. Configuring IIS to do so would be the simplest solution. This then becomes an IIS question, not an OS X related question.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an Apple specific question, but the simplest way to do this is to use the IP address of the laptop. There are various ways of determining the IP address of the laptop. You may be able to find it by hovering your mouse over the wifi icon in the taskbar, or if not open a command window and run 'ipconfig'.

Once you have the ip address, you can browse to it from the iPad at the URL:

http://a.b.c.d/

where a.b.c.d is the IP address of the laptop.

You will have to ensure your Windows firewall is allowing access and ensure IIS is listening to this IP address - by default it listens to all IP addresses on the machine, so unless you changed it, you  should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try hostname instead of IP. And make sure that your webserver is allowing access from other IP as well instead of just 127.0.0.1/localhost

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what your server software is listening for. Is it just a hostname? an IP-address? Usually, you should be able to use the *http://hostname.local* address, and it should work over the ad-hock network.

A clever little network utility called [Localghost](http://scotchi.net/localghost/) should work with any ad-hoc network you create on the same machine as the server, by the by. If you have special hostname needs.

Comment: the server (laptop) is expecting a full url http://subdomain.domain.co.uk  when I enter this into the ipad I get: Safari cannot open the page because it is not connected to the internet.